# Which issue tracker do you recommend?

Tags: api, wiki, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I am looking for an open source issue tracker with

- Multiple projects
- Wiki
- Web API to integrate with CRM and other clients
- Optionally Extendible via custom plugins or modules
- Preferably written in PHP or Python. I am okay with other languages as long as it works on Unix/Linux

Comment: Similar question, might be useful, has 116 answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've happily used [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and [Redmine](http://redmine.org/) for various personal projects.

Trac is written in Python while Redmine is written in Ruby (leveraging the Rails framework).

Redmine has built-in multiple project feature while Trac planned supporting it in 0.12 (already available in a branch).

You would also have to make your choice depending on the SCM you're planning to use:

- Redmine supports SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs
- Trac supports SVN and Mercurial (support for Git available with a [plugin available on Trac Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin)).

Comment: Trac and Redmine seem close to my requirement. Do they come with web API so that I can integrate the tool with a CRM? I am looking to build single sign on facility for the company users as well as customers. Nobody should require more than one account. If it is possible, I would like to hook-up the tool with the CRM work flow. Basically, I am looking for a software that has features like code.google.com project hosting.

Comment: I've just been a user. However you can have a look at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment and http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Developer_Guide

Answer (score 1):

Mantis http://www.mantisbt.org/

Answer (score 0):

I used Bugzilla at another job a few years ago, but I think it's only bug tracking.

Where I'm at now, we use FogBugz and it allows you to track cases, has wiki capabilities and even integrates with source control software. I believe there is a plugin architecture, but I haven't really looked at it.

However, I think it only programmed in ASP which most likely means IIS unless the Mono project has an ASP compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

For my personal projects, where I'm the only developer (and in many cases the only user), I have a self-made issue tracker that I made years ago, when the only big name in (free)issue trackers was Bugzilla, which I didn't like.

For a new multideveloper project I'm working on, we're using [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It's written in Ruby (on Rails) but it's easy to set up on Linux, supports a host of source control systems, has plugins and a wiki (including plugins to change the wiki syntax; I wrote one to do Mediawiki-style syntax since it was more familiar to the people using it). I don't know about it's API/integration but with plugins, odds are you can either find or write something to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question about eleven months ago. I have been using Redmine and am pleased with the results. At the time of posting the question, Redmine didn't have an HTTP API, now it does. I have also recommended Redmine to others.

The reasons I like Redmine are:

1. Support for multiple projects
2. Integrated issue tracker, wiki, repository browser, forum and news feeds
3. HTTP API

Answer (score 0):

I used [trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) for quite some time for a team of 4 developers. It worked well for us and provides most of the features you are looking for (integrations, wiki).

Other than that, you should look into Redmine and OTRS.

This [article](http://usersnap.com/blog/open-source-bug-tracking/) also gives a good review on the best open source bug trackers.